# QuickfixJ | Disable partial logging in quickfixj

Tags: quickfixj

How to disable logging only for outgoing and incoming messages (Except the admin messages and heart beat) in quickfixJ?

I tried passing false values to the ScreenLogfactory constructor, still could see the incoming and outgoing messages

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create your own log and factory by implementing `quickfix.Log`, add your specific logic to `onIncoming` and `onOutgoing` and pass your created log factory to your application instead of the ScreenLogFactory.

Comment: can you give a code example on how to create a custom log factory

Comment: Take a look at https://github.com/quickfix-j/quickfixj/blob/master/quickfixj-core/src/main/java/quickfix/ScreenLog.java and https://github.com/quickfix-j/quickfixj/blob/master/quickfixj-core/src/main/java/quickfix/ScreenLogFactory.java respectively.